# How can get List of Object from resource file

Tags: android

I have build, this on String.xml in my Android Application:

```
   <string-array name="alerts_value_set">
            <AlertValueSet>
                <valueSetOid>2.16.840.1.113883.1.11.20.4</valueSetOid>
                <code>106190000</code>
                <codeSystem>2.16.840.1.113883.6.96</codeSystem>
                <displayName>Allergy</displayName>
                <codeSystemName>SNOMED CT</codeSystemName>

            </AlertValueSet>
            <AlertValueSet>
                <valueSetOid>2.16.840.1.113883.1.11.20.4</valueSetOid>
                <code>281647001</code>
                <codeSystem>2.16.840.1.113883.6.96</codeSystem>
                <displayName>Adverse Reaction</displayName>
                <codeSystemName>SNOMED CT</codeSystemName>
            </AlertValueSet>
            <AlertValueSet>
                <valueSetOid>2.16.840.1.113883.1.11.20.4</valueSetOid>
                <code>282100009</code>
                <codeSystem>2.16.840.1.113883.6.96</codeSystem>
                <displayName>Adverse reaction to substance</displayName>
                <codeSystemName>SNOMED CT</codeSystemName>
            </AlertValueSet>
            <AlertValueSet>
                <valueSetOid>2.16.840.1.113883.1.11.20.4</valueSetOid>
                <code>160244002</code>
                <codeSystem>2.16.840.1.113883.6.96</codeSystem>
                <displayName>No known allergies</displayName>
                <codeSystemName>SNOMED CT</codeSystemName>
            </AlertValueSet>
        </string-array>
```

Now, there is a way to get this List programmatically by code?

I have also create this class (whit getter and setter):

```
public class AlertValueSet {
    String valueSetOid;
    String code;
    String codeSystem;
    String displayName;
    String codeSystemName;
}
```

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_xml_parsers.htm

Answer (score 0):

try the code to get List of object from xml file

```
List<AlertValueSet> alertvalueset = null;
    try {
        XMLPullParserHandler parser = new XMLPullParserHandler();
        alertvalueset = parser.parse(getAssets().open("string.xml"));

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: What if he adds a new string resource in the same file?

Comment: @TimCastelijns then I think he need to add it in its class as property

Comment: What if its unrelated and doesn't belong in the class?